# UPDATE using collection

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am testing a code in which basically I want to delete from a table using values stored in a table type variable.  it's a list of ID.  so far I have tried the below..

```
DECLARE 
 TYPE REC_TYPE IS TABLE OF DEPT.DEPARTMENT_ID%TYPE;
 T_TYPE REC_TYPE;

BEGIN

    SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID BULK COLLECT INTO T_TYPE
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID FROM DEPT
        INTERSECT
        SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID FROM EMP
     );

     FORALL C IN T_TYPE.FIRST..T_TYPE.LAST
       DELETE FROM DEPT 
        WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID=T_TYPE(C).DEPARTMENT_ID;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQL%ROWCOUNT);
    END;



CREATE TABLE DEPT 
AS
SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENTS;

CREATE TABLE EMP 
AS
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

but i am getting the error

```
PLS-00487: Invalid reference to variable 'DEPT.DEPARTMENT_ID%TYPE'
ORA-06550: line 17, column 29:
PL/SQL: ORA-22806: not an object or REF
ORA-06550: line 16, column 8:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
```

not sure where to correct. any help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: `WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID=T_TYPE(C);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that

```
TYPE REC_TYPE IS TABLE OF DEPT.DEPARTMENT_ID%TYPE;
```

is a table of the data type of Department_id.

So it is not a row, therefor the call to

```
T_TYPE(C).DEPARTMENT_ID;
```

is invalid, since there's no department_id in t_type(c).
The reference should be to

```
T_TYPE(C)
```

instead.

Although old, this is interesting: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm